# Is it possible to add the Proxy-Server plus Port to the HTTP Request Header (error: statusCode=407)

Tags: .net, proxy, http-headers, httprequest, http-status-code-407

**Problem**:

I try to send an HTTP Request to get an access token (Method: POST). It leads to the error:
tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=407

For the request I'm using die Windows Application Postman.

**What I have done so far?**

I recognized the there is a proxy server in between which is blocking the request. I resolved that issue by unlock another proxy-server address under the Port 8080. I added this proxy-server as custom proxy configuration to the proxy settings in Postman (see picture: [Postman Proxy Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICNre.png)). Then it was possible to send the request without any issue.

**But:**

I must use in an automation Project the Software UiPath-Studio, where I can send HTTP requests via an activity (“functional software brick”). There it is not possible to choose any proxy settings via an additional option (correct me if I'm wrong). I'm just able to add Parameters and Headers of an HTTP Request. The Activity seems to use the global system proxy.

**Question:**

Is it possible to add the Proxy-Server plus Port to the HTTP Request Header to avoid the error: tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=407?

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: If I am getting it correctly your issue is to get the proxy setup. If yes then I would suggest that create proxy in your prferred langugage(.Net/JAVA/Node) then just run that application before your workflow. Or please explain the main issue in just a brief points

Comment: @AtulChaudhary: Thank you for your advice. That's exactly what I did in end. Ijust have written my own code activity.